# How do I uninstall Visual Studio Enterprise without uninstalling Visual Studio Community?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My VS-Enterprise license expired over the new year so I installed the community version.

When I go to the control panel it just shows me **"Visual Studio Community 2017 (2)"** and no option for Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. Also, when I search for the enterprise version and **right-click uninstall**, it brings me to the same **"Visual Studio Community 2017 (2)"** in the control panel.

Is there a way of uninstalling enterprise through the community version?

Comment: Just uninstall it from Visual Studio Installer. They are installed side by side. You'll see both of them in Visual Studio Installer. Remove the one you don't want

Answer (score 3):

## [Uninstall Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio)

1. Find the Visual Studio Installer on your computer.

   For example, on a computer running Windows 10 Anniversary Update, select Start and scroll to the letter V, where it is listed as Visual Studio Installer.

   [image]

   > Alternatively, you can find the Visual Studio Installer in the following location:
   >
   > ```
   >  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe
   > ```
2. Click to start the installer, click the Details icon icon, and then click Uninstall.

   [image]
3. Click OK to confirm your choice.

   [image]

## [Uninstall Visual Studio Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio#uninstall-visual-studio-installer)

To completely remove all installations of Visual Studio 2017 as well as the Visual Studio Installer from your machine, uninstall it from Apps & Features.

1. Open Apps & Features. For example, in Windows 10, select Start, and in the search bar, type Apps and Features.
2. Find Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
3. Click Uninstall.